# Arduino IDE. How do I use labels in a macro?

Tags: assembly

It's the Arduino Uno. I've spent hours reading on the internet but found nothing yet. If you use a label in the macro, the 2nd time it's called you get a duplicate label error.

Comment: Please provide your code and the exact error message and describe what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I suggest only using [local lables](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Local-Labels-1) in assembly macros.

Comment: `Its the aduino uno` ... no it's not ... the problem you describe has nothing to do with the type of arduino

Comment: Many thanks Edgar Bonet. Local labels is exactly what I  was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make the question clearer, let's take a simple example. Consider
the following assembly macro that implements a delay loop:

```lisp
.macro short_delay
    clr  r0
repeat:
    dec  r0
    brne repeat
.endm
```

and use it in a program that repeatedly blinks the built-in LED of an
Arduino Uno (a faster version of “Blink”):

```lisp
main:
    sbi  DDRB, PB5   ; set pin 13 = PB5 as output
loop:
    sbi  PORTB, PB5  ; turn PB5 HIGH
    short_delay
    cbi  PORTB, PB5  ; turn PB5 LOW
    short_delay
    rjmp loop
```

When the assembler expands the macro, it ends up with this:

```lisp
main:
    sbi  DDRB, PB5   ; set PB5 as output
loop:
    sbi  PORTB, PB5  ; turn PB5 HIGH
    ; start of short_delay macro
    clr  r0
repeat:
    dec  r0
    brne repeat
    ; end of short_delay macro
    cbi  PORTB, PB5  ; turn PB5 LOW
    ; start of short_delay macro
    clr  r0
repeat:
    dec  r0
    brne repeat
    ; end of short_delay macro
    rjmp loop
```

and this fails with

```
Error: symbol `repeat' is already defined
```

The solution to this problem is to use, inside the macro, only [local
labels](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Local-Labels-1). These labels are just numbers. When using them, one has to
append the suffix “b” (for backwards) or “f” (forwards) depending on
whether the label is defined before or after the point where it is being
referenced.

The nice thing about local labels is that they are... well... local, and
thus they can be safely reused many times. The assembler disambiguates
them by choosing the definition that is *closer* to the point of use,
along the specified direction. With a local label (I choose `0`), the
delay macro becomes:

```lisp
.macro short_delay
    clr  r0
0:  dec  r0
    brne 0b  ; the branch target is the preceding label `0'
.endm
```

When the macro is expanded, the main program becomes:

```lisp
main:
    sbi  DDRB, PB5   ; set PB5 as output
loop:
    sbi  PORTB, PB5  ; turn PB5 HIGH
    clr  r0
0:  dec  r0
    brne 0b
    cbi  PORTB, PB5  ; turn PB5 LOW
    clr  r0
0:  dec  r0
    brne 0b
    rjmp loop
```

Although repeated, the label is not ambiguous, as `brne 0b` always
refers to the *closest* label `0` along the **b**ackwards direction.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome, this is the same thing I had problems a few years back. Define the label in the `macro` (function) and it will be local and not available to the rest of the world. You can use the same label as many times as you want they just need to be inside a `macro`.

```
void macro(int label) 
{ 
   Do something with label and then exit;
}
```

You can do whatever you want, say get the value of several pins to see if they are all on then use the return true or false. When you leave the macro all of the variables will be lost and the memory returned to the heap. This is done in several ways in many of the libraries.

Comment: The question is about the use of labels in assembly macros, not about the use of variables in C++ functions.